# How can I delete the first element from an array while assuring the result is still an array in jsonata?

Tags: jsonata

I would like to create a jsonata expression that deletes the first element of an array.
There is a very simple expression that does that :

```
array1#$pos[$pos!=0]
```

but when applying this expression to an array having 2 elements, then this expression is not returning an array containing only the second element, but it is returning the 2nd element as you can see in the following jsonata test

https://try.jsonata.org/gl0l_wnGe

[image]

So this is not what I want.
I am looking for a jsonata expression that for `"new_array1"` doesn't return `"two"` but returns `["two"]`.

This is a bit simplified version of the actual problem I am having.  The actual problem is that I want to delete an element with a specific index in the array and I am having the same problem when the array has 2 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning `"two"` instead of `["two"]` because of the sequence flattening rules https://docs.jsonata.org/processing#sequences.  Adding an empty `[]` to the end of the path expression will turn the sequence into an array.  Try this:

```
{
    "new_array1": array1#$pos[$pos!=0][],
    "new_array2": array2#$pos[$pos!=0][]
}
```

https://try.jsonata.org/BaO2T7_9i